# HTML POST Redirection issue

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, forms, http-post

I am trying to create a new login page for my website and I was using nodejs to create the login part. so I use the html post method to pass parameters.. so basically I have a sign in part, sign up part and forgot password part. Ive each form action given to path /local , /signup and /forgot respectively..Ive a single page theme. so there is only one index file which handlese all these features.  so when I submit these forms... if its unsuccesul it will go to the url http://www.mycustomurl/local or http://www.mycustomurl/signup or http://www.mycustomurl/local/forgot and gets redirected to these pages.. and I have created duplicates of page index.html with filenames signup.html, local.html and forgot.html. Is it possible to redirect the form submit to current page itself?? Which is the best method?

Comment: If you use single page theme, how about using ajax?

Comment: using ajax is not secure as the post request paramer has private info like password

Comment: Although you use form, your form POST data is still visible.

Comment: @user1371896 are you using expressjs with node?

Comment: yes Im using expressjs.. I dnt think POST data is visible as we r using this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you should be able to do it with expressJS. You can set up different routes to serve the same files. Something like this should work.

```
app.post('local', function(request, response){
    //your code that does stuff here
    //if successful 
        //do your action
    //if unsuccessful
        //serve your single page
        response.sendfile(path_to_file_index);
});

app.post('signup', function(request, response){
    //your code that does stuff here
    //if successful 
        //do your action
    //if unsuccessful
        //serve your single page
        response.sendfile(path_to_file_index);
});

app.post('forgot', function(request, response){
    //your code that does stuff here
    //if successful 
        //do your action
    //if unsuccessful
        //serve your single page
        response.sendfile(path_to_file_index);
});
```

Comment: so is it possible to pass response variable to the index file?? should nt we be suing response.render function as we need to display the variable values which shows the cause of sign up error like that.. and  once the submit button is clicked it goes to the corespnding url and shows file not found message

Comment: This depends. If you're using a templating engine, it's trivial enough to grab the variable values from the request and assign it to your view (your index file). If that were the case, I don't think you'd use `.sendfile` though. You would use whatever output function your templating engine requires. You won't be able to do it with `.sendfile`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..we are using ejs templating.. so its response.render(path_to_file_index) ..I will surely let u know if the above solution wrked or not...

Answer (score 0):

Redirection is possible via a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.abc.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !oldexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```